# Laravel Vapor Queue Dynamic DB Connection Issue for Different Requests

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue, laravel-vapor

I have Laravel Project running on vapor. (using SQS for Queue Driver)
I have 2 webhook endpoints.

```
/webhook1
/webhook2
```

In `webhook1` It's dispatching `Job1`

In `webhook2` It's dispatching `Job2`

I needed to save in different database for `webhook2` so I made 2nd configuration in `mysql2`

And in `constructs` of both `webhook2` handler and `Job2` class, I added following dynamic DB configuration.

```
config([
   'database.connections.mysql' => config('database.connections.mysql2'),
]);
```

So I assumed in `webhook1` and `Job1`, data will be saved in `database1` (mysql connection DB) and in `webhook2` and `Job2`, data will be saved in `database2` (mysql2 connection DB) but for some reason inside `Job1` it was interacting with `database2`.

It was fine in `webhook1` though. Only issue inside Queue which is `Job1`

How can I isolate this DB connection?